# Symbolic manipulation of terms in Coq

Tags: coq

Proof states like this often arise in my Coq studies:

```
1 goal
n : nat
IHn : fib_v1 n <= fib_v1 (S n)
______________________________________(1/1)
fib_v1 (S n) <= fib_v1 (S (S n))
```

Coq complains that it can't unify `n` with `S n` and `S n` with `S (S n)`. In paper and pen, it would be easy to introduce a symbolic manipulation within the goal, say `t = S n`, or even `n = S n`, then the induction hypothesis would become applicable. It doesn't seem to work that way in Coq. How one moves on in a situation like this?

Answer (score 3):

I think here Coq rightfully complains. If you are proving you property by induction, it’s normal that you induction hypothesis is some `P(n)` and that your conclusion is `P(S n)` and you can’t simply use the former to prove the latter… Otherwise anything would be provable by induction!

In your case, what you probably would have to do is to unfold the definitions of `fib_v1` in the conclusion, so that you can relate `fib_v1 (S n)` and `fib_v1 (S (S n))` to `fib_v1 n` and hopefully use your induction hypothesis to conclude.

If you wish to do a local definition, you can do that in Coq, using eg `set (t := S n) in *.` (the `set` tactic introduces the definition, and the `in *` part replaces every occurrence of the body in your hypotheses and goal by the variable name).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might be wrong but in this special case I do see the induction hypothesis could be rightfully used to justify the goal as the meaning of `P(n) -> P(S n)` is merely the same as the meaning of 'P(S n) -> P(S S(n))'.

Comment: This question reminds me of a previous one of mine. In `forall a b c : nat, a + b = a + c -> b = c` it seems so easy to cancel `a` by adding `-a` to both sides. I'm still not sure if there's a similar technique in Coq.

Comment: As for your first comment: what might confuse you is that if you have `forall x, P(x) -> P(S x)` then indeed you can instantiate this with `S n` to get `P(S(n)) -> P(S(S n))`, but this is not what you have in your situation, as your induction hypothesis holds only a specific (albeit unspecified) `n`, but not universally. Again, if you could always deduce `P (S n)` from `P n`, then any property would be provable by induction.

Comment: As for the second, yes, this is provable. You can either use the corresponding lemma of the standard library (called `Nat.add_cancel_l`) using the `apply` tactic, or use a more powerful automation tactic, such as `ring` or `lia`.